# Id : denoting the identity mapping of Rn

Tags: image-processing, image-registration

I would like to know the pixel values of Identity mapping Id; it is generally used in image registration. Say h is deformation; then, ---for Id+h--- they call warped image.
But, I couldn't get that how to embed Id  to matlab; what is the value of it? Is it something identity matrix?
Best

Comment: is this the eigen matrice

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0.1;
stopcr=eps
I1=dicomread('1.dcm');
I2=dicomread('2.dcm');
maxiter=1000;
normdiv=inf;
while( (abs(b)>= stopcr) &(iter <=maxiter))

div1= (I1-I2).* uint16(imgradient(I2));

lap= 0.6 * (imgradient(imgradient(I2)));
lap=uint16(lap);
b=(div1+lap);
div= a* b;
div=uint16(div);
normdiv=abs(div);
solnew= w +div;

w=solnew;
end
w;
b
imcontrast(imshow(w))
```

Here what I did; I initiliazed the w by assigning it the fixed image (I1). This code aims to register I2 into the I1.
I dont know to assess my code. On the other hand what is Id denotes identity mapping. Can you somebody share his/her idea,

Comment: Is there anyone who can tell me what Id (identity mapping) is because I would like to implement basic image registration algorithms